# XNA ActiveX Control - Cannot find custom ContentReader when running in IE

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, activex, xna

**What I Have**

MyGraphicsLibrary.Content.Pipeline.dll

```
public class MyModelProcessor { }
public class MyModelContent { }

[ContentTypeWriter]
public class MyModelContentWriter : ContentWriter<MyModelContent>
{
   protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, MeshDataContent value)
   {
       value.Write(output);
   }

   public override string GetRuntimeType(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
   {
       return "MyGraphicsLibrary.MyModel, MyGraphicsLibrary";
   }

   public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
   {
       return "MyGraphicsLibrary.MyModelReader, MyGraphicsLibrary";
   }
}
```

MyGraphicsLibrary.dll: Strongly Named

```
public class GraphicsDeviceControl : System.Windows.Forms.Panel { }
public class MyModel { }
public class MyModelReader : ContentTypeReader<MyModel> { }
```

`GraphicsDeviceControl` is based on [this XNA sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1).
ActiveXApplication.dll: Strongly Named, Registered for COM Interop

```
 [Guid("")]
 [ProgId("ActiveXApplication.ActiveXControl")]
 [ComVisible(true)]
 public class ActiveXControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl { }
 public class MyGraphicsDeviceControl : MyGraphicsLibrary.GraphicsDeviceControl { }
```

`ActiveXControl` is the main UI for the application I'm embedding in IE7/8 with the `<object>` tag.  The site the control is hosted on has been added to Trusted Sites. `MyGraphicsDeviceControl` loads models based on information passed to `ActiveXControl` from the web page. The models loaded were created from FBX models with `MyModelProcessor` and written with `MyModelContentWriter`. I am currently using XNA 3.0.

**The Problem**

When `MyGraphicsDeviceControl` executes the following line:

```
this.contentManager.Load<MyModel>("modelName")
```

I receive the following error:

> Error loading "pathToModel\modelName". Cannot find ContentTypeReader MyGraphicsLibrary.MyModelReader, MyGraphicsLibrary.

This error does not occur when using `ActiveXControl` in a Windows Forms application.  When using the default XNA model classes, the error does not occur (I'm trying to use the custom model class rather than abusing the Tag property of the XNA Model class).  Using Reflector, I traced through `ContentManager.Load<T>` looking for the source of the exception and found it to happen when XNA attempts to call `Type.GetType()` using the string defined in `MyModelContentWriter.GetRuntimeReader()` which returns null.

**The Question**

Any thoughts as to why Type.GetType() is returning null when trying to load MyModelReader and not XNA's ModelReader when running in IE?

**UPDATE:**

After looking into the issue some more, I was able to find a way to get my custom model class to load when running in IE.  By adding a handler for `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`, I was able to return the assembly containing `MyModelReader` which allowed the `Type.GetType()` call in the XNA code to succeed.

Based on the information I read about Reflection and assembly loading, I assume I was able to use the XNA model class without a problem because the XNA assemblies are registered in the GAC where as mine is not.  However, `MyGraphicsLibrary.dll` was already loaded in the `AppDomain`, so I'm not entirely sure why it was unable to resolve the assembly.  I assume it has something to do with the context in which it was loaded, but I'm not sure which context the assemblies are loading in when running in IE.

Answer (score 0):

set ContentManager.RootDirctory to abs path.

Comment: The RootDirectory of the ContentManager is not the problem here; the content pipeline's inner workings are finding the content in its raw .xnb format, but can't find the type required to deserialize it into an instance of the target type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full, assembly qualified name of the type of your content reader? I noticed that your content writer's `GetRuntimeReader` override doesn't specify a public key token, a culture, or a version.

I've had problems like yours before, and all of them were caused by me not specifying the runtime type correctly.

This can be obtained via `typeof(<your content reader type>).AssemblyQualifiedName`.

The `Type.GetType(string)` method returns null when it can't find the type, so:

1. the string that's being passed doesn't give the fully qualified type of the name (that's my guess), or
2. The type's containing assembly hasn't been loaded in the runtime context of the application you're trying to load content from. Have you added a reference to your content pipeline extension to your main project?